# the way babel-plugin-transform-class-properties handle the properties

Tags: babeljs

why does babel-plugin-transform-class-properties add properties which the value is a function to the instance rather than the constructor's prototype?

```js
class Bork {
//Property initializer syntax
instanceProperty = "bork";
boundFunction = () => {
  return this.instanceProperty;
}

//Static class properties
static staticProperty = "babelIsCool";
static staticFunction = function() {
    return Bork.staticProperty;
  }
}

let myBork = new Bork;

//Property initializers are not on the prototype.
console.log(myBork.__proto__.boundFunction); // > undefined

//Bound functions are bound to the class instance.
console.log(myBork.boundFunction.call(undefined)); // > "bork"

//Static function exists on the class.
console.log(Bork.staticFunction()); // > "babelIsCool"
```

why the property "boundFunction" not on the prototype?

Comment: Please atleast share with us some come, else it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: i added the code